# Django how use in template list of queryset

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm a beginner in Django.

I have these three classes

```
class Escape(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Salle(models.Model):
    salle = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    escape = models.ForeignKey(Escape, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.salle


class Enigme(models.Model):
    enigme_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    salle = models.ForeignKey(Salle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.enigme_name
```

I try to display in my template a list of **enigme** for each **salle**. I cannot figure out how to build my view to display each set of enigme for each salle.

This is my view :

```
def salle_escape(request):
    escape_named = 'NumW'
    list_salle = Salle.objects.filter(escape__name=escape_named)
    enigme = []
    for e in list_salle:
        enigme.append( Enigme.objects.filter(salle__salle=e) )

    # enigme = Enigme.objects.filter(salle__salle=
    context = { 
            'escape' : Escape.objects.get(name=escape_named),
            'salle'  : list_salle,
            'enigme'  : enigme,
            }
    return render(request, 'chat/salle_escape.html', context)
```

This my template :

```
<!-- chat/templates/chat/room.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Chat Room</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ escape.name }}</h1>
    <h2>Liste des salles</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for s in salle %}
        <li>{{ s.salle }} {{ forloop.counter0 }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {{ enigme }}
</body>
</html>
```

In my browser displays for {{ enigme }} this :

```
[<QuerySet [<Enigme: Lanterne>, <Enigme: Coussin>, <Enigme: Biblot>]>,
<QuerySet [<Enigme: Operation>, <Enigme: Cle triangle>, <Enigme: Miroir>, <Enigme: Lumiere>]>, 
<QuerySet [<Enigme: Oiseau>, <Enigme: Epingle>]>]
```

Thank you if you can bring me help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to display each set of `Enigme` for each `Salle`, then you can do a reverse lookup. You should be able to do it in the template:

```
    {% for s in salle %}
        <li>{{ s.salle }} {{ forloop.counter0 }}</li>
        {% for enigme in s.enigme_set.all %}
            <li>{{ enigme }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

You can acces the related `Enigme` objects without setting it up in the view. As you are a beginner, I would recommend you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) part of the Django docs.

Comment: Thank you really much I didn't know we could access like this the enigme table. I have no error with your code but it doesn't the enigme text, only empty bullets. I'm reading the docs you have advised me. I will come back if I can find the solution.

Comment: It's really weird ... It counts the true number of enigmes (There are as much as empty bullet than enigme number). I have juste modified {{ engime }} to {{ engime.enigme_name }}...  Nothing change. When I try in the python shell it works.

Comment: Thank Daniel, finally it didn't work because I didn't notice the little mistake in **engime** which should have been **enigme**. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, I have edited the answer to have the correct spelling of `enigme`. You say "finally it didn't work" or do you mean it did work?

Comment: Ho yes.... I meant **"It did work"** ... Another mistake o_o'  Thank you for your superb help !